# It's possible to create one service that calls two proxy-services in loopback 4?

Tags: loopback

I have two Rest data sources, with their respective proxy-service. 
But can I create one service that calls the right proxy-service instead of doing it directly on the controller? Is that possible?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

At the end, yes it is.

Just create a new service with this option:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EYzV.png)
And then inject the proxy-services you need. On this way you can delegate some logic from controller to this service.